# Create column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have this dataset:

```
        Players       Material_bough
1         X1                Wood
2         X2                Iron
3         X1                Stone
```

I would like to create a new column that shows the sum of materials a player bought.

```
        Players       Material_bough         Material_total
1         X1                Wood                  2
2         X2                Iron                  1
3         X1                Stone                 2
```

As Wood + Stone = 2 materials.

I think I should use groupby but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is same as count `Players` without aggregating by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Material_total'] = df.groupby('Players')['Material_bough'].transform('size')
```

Or:

```
df['Material_total'] = df.groupby('Players')['Material_bough'].transform('count')
```

Comment: I assume that if I want to count the Material_bough instead I use df.groupby('Players')['Material_bough'].transform('count')

Comment: Additional question if you don't mind, if same value reoccurred, does it adds up ?

Comment: Not sure if 100% understand, but agter change value if run code it recount it very nice.

Comment: If instead of Stone I have Wood again, does it output 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.